# Piping to process with c++

Tags: c++

I have finally worked out how to get stdin and stdout to pipe between the main app and a process created with CreateProcess (win32) or exec (linux).  Now I am interested in harnessing the piping nature of an app.  The app I am running can be piped into:

```
eg: cat file.txt | grep "a"
```

If I want to run "grep", sending the contents of "file.txt" to it (which I have in a buffer in my c++ app), how do I do this?  I assume I don't just pump it down stdin, or am I wrong.  Is that what I do?

Comment: To improve efficiency and general cleverness, skip "cat" and redirect grep's stdin to read from the file:  grep "a" < file.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what you do: read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`.

One of the strokes of genius behind linux is the simplicity of redirecting input and output almost effortlessly, as long as your apps obey some very simple, basic rules.  For example: send data to `stdout` and errors or informational messages to `stderr`.  That makes it easy for a user to keep track of status, and you can still use your app to send data to a pipe.

You can also redirect data (from `stdout`) and messages (from `stderr`) independently:

```
myapp | tail -n 5 > myapp.data # Save the last 5 lines, display msgs
myapp 2> myapp.err | sort      # Sort the output, send msgs to a file
myapp 2> /dev/null             # Throw msgs away, display output
myapp > myapp.out 2>&1         # Send all output (incl. msgs) to a file
```

Redirection may be a bit confusing at first, but you'll find the time spent learning will be well worth it!